# Render using all cores except one (or N)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, performance

Is there a way to configure the Blender Render or Cycles to use all the available cores in the machine except for one (or N) of them? I'd like to set a render off in the background but leave me with a core to catch up on emails, browse, etc.?

I've tried using a fixed number of cores for rendering but this means if I swap the blend file between machines from, say a 6 core machine to a 12 core machine, then I have to manually reconfigure how many cores to use.

Thanks

Comment: This *might* be possible through drivers, but I am not a driver wizzard so I will leave that to someone else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to have a script file in each of your blends containing this:

```
import bpy
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

cores_idle = 1    # <- SET THIS

# cpu_count() returns logical cores not physical
cores_available = cpu_count()
cores_enabled = max(1, cores_available - cores_idle)

for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    scene.render.threads_mode = 'FIXED'
    scene.render.threads = cores_enabled
```

Give it a `.py` extension and check *register* so it is run by blender when you open the file (this should be also enabled in *Preferences*). You can also save this script into your *Start Up* file <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>.

Or for rendering you can [execute it from the command line with](https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line.html#python-options) `--python`, without having to modify your startup or `.blend` files.

Comment: Don't you need to add the register and unregister functions?

Comment: That's only needed for add-ons.

Comment: @someonewithpc nope, it's enough that it get's run. We don't need to register panels classes etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is a *very* **simple** way to do this, **if you don't care about reading it per computer.** If you want it to be done automatically, see the other answer. (yes, I made this before I read your whole question.) :P

1. Scroll down the *render* panel to the **performance** section.
2. *Select* **fixed** threads
3. **Change** the number of threads to the number you would like.

The illustration *below* shows the **cpu** used by each *thread* over the render of *two* frames.

[image]

Keep in mind about this method.

- This method is based on **threads**, not cores.
- It **will not** always choose the same, or last thread of your pc to deactivate.
- The *"auto-detect"* method will use all threads.
- The tread you have chosen to leave out **will still work**, because now it is running *the rest of the processes on your computer.*
- During the render *of a single frame*, the "dormant" thread **may change.**